# InstallShield hyperlink in License Agreeement

Tags: installshield

I have a 'hyperlink' in the Installer Eula document (License Agreement). The problem is that clicking the link does not open the page in the web browser. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

via http://blogs.msdn.com/robmen/archive/2006/05/30/610950.aspx

> The RICHEDIT control does not support
>   hyperlinks. You can color the text
>   blue and underline it but the text
>   still won't be a clickable hyperlink.
>
> Hyperlinks in general are just not
>   supported by the native MSI UI. Sad
>   but true.